# Correctly Updating ComboBox Selected Item in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Given the below ViewModel code - `cmbxFields` is bound to a ComboBox ItemSource, `SelectedcmbxField` is bound to the selected item - the ComboBox selected item doesn't update till I navigate away and back to the view (`Page`). What is the correct way to do this in MVVM to get the ComboBox to be updated instantly?

```
public ObservableCollection<string> cmbxFields { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public string SelectedCmbxField { get; set; }

private async Task LoadWorkspaceFields()
{
    cmbxFields.Clear();
    foreach (var curField in availableFields.OrderBy(x =>x.Name).Select(x => x.Name))
    {
        cmbxFields.Add(curField);
    }

    SelectedCmbxField = cmbxFields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("Some Text"));
}
```

I've tried the following on my ComboBox XAML-

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedcmbxField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: The class containing the property should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: You should find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577978/mvvm-binding-selecteditem-to-update-listview)

Comment: @Stefan It should, yes but you can also directly ref the `OnChanged` in the specific property setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int intValue;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public int MyIntValue
  {
    get => intValue;
    set
    {
      intValue = value;
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyIntValue)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. FYI, note that you need to assign to the Public property, and not to the private variable in order to trigger the update.